# Gang of Four: lexi editor c++ source

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm reading ["Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable OOSW"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612).  In chapter two, the authors provide a case study of an editor they refer to as Lexi, which seems to be written in C++.  I've looked around everywhere, but the only [useful link](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/design_patterns/the_lexi_editor/the_lexi_editor.html) I could find said this:

> The Gof tell us in a note that Lexi is
>   based on "Doc, a text editing
>   application developed by Calder". But
>   this paper only outlines an editor,
>   without any source. And I even believe
>   today that Lexi **never truly existed as
>   a program**.

The link provides Delphi source.  I'm after C++, cause that's what I'm comfortable with, and that's what's used in the book.

Does anybody know where I can find C++ source for Lexi?  If the original never existed, it would be good to find something that I can use as a base.  I really don't feel like writing my own text editor from scratch just so I can work through the case study in this book.

Comment: if you never find it and really want to work with text editor sources, i recommend scintilla as one good starting point.

Comment: Gang of Four is the best about book of design patterns. I'm reading it now.
I was finding a C++ code of Lexi exitor too, but I don't find it. What is the question you have about editor?

Comment: @Justin: personally, I'm not that thrilled about working with text editors -- it's just that the book starts off with them, and I figured that I could dive into the pattern part if I had the Lexi sources.

Comment: @G-71: my question is: **where is the C++ source code for the Lexi editor?**

Comment: Have you tried connecting with the GoF authors on LinkedIn?  Get the answer straight from the source!

Answer (score 6):

Doc was developed using the InterViews UI toolkit. I believe that doc source is part of the InterViews distribution. Doc was used to typeset Paul's thesis. (Paul Calder was my lecturer at Flinders University)

If you look at the InterViews code you might be surprised. It was developed before modern C++ existed. For example, there are no templates. And there are no comments in the code.

To my understanding, Lexi never existed. It was created as an example for the book by GoF.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a Java implementation can help, being it more similar to c++. Here it is:
[jexieditor - A WYSIWYG editor based on JavaSE](http://code.google.com/p/jexieditor/). I have not had a look at the code yet, anyway

Comment: How do you run the application? Using MacOS.

Comment: I don't know the details of using MacOs, anyway, after uncompressing the file, in the dist subfolder there is a file start.bat, valid for windows but it should give you the idea. It has just 3 lines. I guess you can just open it and copy the command line for launching the jar file: ( java -classpath jexi.jar;swt.jar;res.jar com.crackj2ee.jexi.ui.Application ) . Or maybe adapt the batch file to MacOs environment...

Answer (score 2):

I may be showing my age here but are you sure about C++? I have a funny feeling that when that book came out originally it may have been oriented toward Smalltalk. Its just something nagging at the back of my mind, I can't substantiate it I'm afraid

Comment: A lot of the patterns were first discovered/developed in Smalltalk, but the book covers both C++ and Smalltalk, iirc.  I haven't actually read the book in a long time. :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently implementing Lexi analog, pls take a look https://github.com/romaonishuk/LexI. Implementation is still in progress, but most of the described in GoF patterns and concepts are implemented using C++.

Comment: Does it support windows?

Comment: Hi @Kargath, sorry for the delayed response.
I've renewed work on it. You can find current changes in the windows branch: https://github.com/romaonishuk/LexI/tree/windows

Answer (score 0):

This is the code source of LEXI, *written in Delphi unfortunately for you*: [LEXI sources](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/design_patterns/the_lexi_editor/the_lexi_editor.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there's already a link to the Delphi sources in my original question :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the source code *might* be on the CD-ROM version of *Design Patterns* that came out in 1998. According to the [Amazon listing](http://amzn.eu/gpSIMVE), the CD contains (among other things):

> Sample code demonstrating pattern implementation

Furthermore,

> All patterns are compiled from real-world examples and include code that demonstrates how they may be implemented in object-oriented programming languages such as C++ and Smalltalk. Readers who already own the book will want the CD to take advantage of its dynamic search mechanism and ready-to-install patterns.

Whether these code samples include the full Lexi source is impossible to tell from the listing, and the current price of the CD (£86.87) is rather high. But it might be worth checking if any local libraries have the CD in stock.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to find out if a real working Lexi version exists, to have a concrete reference, but I didn't find it.
I found this Java version on GitHub: https://github.com/AmitDutta/lexi
I don't know, maybe it could be useful for someone's purpose here.